# Storing lowercase conversion in a variable in BASH

Tags: bash

I am trying to convert a string into its lowercase and store it in another variable so that I can conduct future operations on it.

```
month= $(echo "${1,,}")
echo $month
```

I also tried the following

```
month= "${1,,}"
echo $month
```

I get a command not found error such as : `"bash: aug: command not found\r\n"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash is very particular about whitespace. Get rid of the space after the equal sign.

```
month=$(echo "${1,,}")
```

Or more directly:

```
month=${1,,}
```

---

When you have the space, Bash parses the line as two separate items:

```
month= $(echo "${1,,}")
^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |          |
   |          +-------> command
   +------------------> variable assignment
```

It tries to execute the result of `$(echo "${1,,}")` as if it were a command. That's why it complains about `aug: command not found`.

It thinks `month=` is a variable assignment of the form `A=foo B=bar command`, which runs `command` with `$A` and `$B` temporarily set to `"foo"` and `"bar"`. When you use this feature the variable assignments are only in effect for the duration of the one command.